# Google speech to text demo - error message "Invalid recognition 'config': bad sample rate hertz."

Tags: google-cloud-speach-to-text

I am trying out https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/ but every attempt has failed. I have a couple of **.amr** files with recorded phone calls, that I want to convert to text. Uploading them directly fails with the following error message:

> We could not decode your audio. Try a different file.

So I converted files to AAC / MP3, but it still fails. Now with a different error message:

> Invalid recognition 'config': bad sample rate hertz.

I have tried a few different sample rates, but I always get the same error. What sample rate is supported? The page doesn't give any hints about supported formats or other details.

Googling this exact phrase didn't return any (!) results.

Comment: Link to the docs: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/

Comment: Sample rates between 8000 Hz and 48000 Hz are supported within Speech-to-Text. https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/basics#sample-rates. Maybe your sample rate is out of the range?

Comment: This happens to me, too. I've tried all possible sampling rates from 48KHz to 8KHz. All returend the same error message except the last one 8KHz, which returned "A server error occured!". Seems like a bloody bug on the Google's API.